# Basis for differentials of a smooth plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a smooth plane curve $C$ cut out by a homogeneous polynomial $f(x,y,z)=0$, how to calculate a basis for the space of global differential forms? There is the adjunction formula which shows that the canonical bundle of $C$ is $\omega_C = \omega_\mathbb{P^2} \otimes O(d)|_C$ where $d$ is the degree of the curve but it's not clear that the map on global sections is surjective.

Comment: The map $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(r)\to \mathcal{O}_C(r)$ is surjective on global sections for any curve in the plane, since the cokernel is contained in  $H^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(r-d))$, where $d=\deg C$ and this is always zero for any $r,d$.